# WinForms App Memory Leak

Tags: vb.net, devforce

I'm using a WinForms App built with IdeaBlade and DevExpress ... It looks to me like the DevExpress controls are causing objects to persist in memory. I'm trying to find what is preventing the garbage collector from removing then with little success.

Can anyone recommend an analysis app that is good at finding what handler, etc is holding an item in memory?

I've used AQTime 7 Pro and .Net Memory Profiler, but neither of them seem to make it clear what is causing the issue.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you specify what DevExpress controls and what objects? Are they connected to the DevExpress controls? Have you tried adding Finalize() overrides to see if the objects are, in fact, leaving memory?

Comment: @minitech - At this stage I'm looking soley at DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl, but every form that uses any DevExpress control or object is having the same issue. What I am noticing, is opening the form with this control adds ~4mb to memory use. When you exit the form, no memory is released. Opening the form again adds 4 more mb to memory. Having a look using AQtime 7 Pro it shows the form, it's controls, and the xtragrid binding manager are still objects in memory, but it doesn't explain what'd holding them there. It seems DevExpress might be the issue.

Comment: You might want to note that the .NET garbage collector can collect unused memory at an arbitrary time, usually when it feels the extra memory is required or when your application is idle for a long time, and so there may not actually be any problem. Try creating several thousand forms, logging the memory usage after each creation, and seeing if there is a drop anywhere. If there is, you probably don't have any problem. The DevExpress controls may simply be loading a large set of shared resources such as images, etc.

Comment: @minitech Yes I know, memory is being released from time to time, but overall the application bloats. In a few hours of serious use it goes from 150mb to 700mb of memory. You can sit there and open/close the same form over and over and that memory is never released.

Comment: I mean try that programmatically. If you have a lot of memory, it might not release, or certain conditions may be slowing the GC down.

Answer (score 1):

[ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) from Red Gate may do the trick.

Disclaimer: Other memory profilers are available.

Comment: Doesn't appear to play nive with DevExpress. Upon opening this application is crashed complaining it couldn't find a DevExpress .dll ... Confusing, yes! I haven't bothered to work out why.

Answer (score 0):

[dotTrace Memory](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and [dotTrace Performance](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) are quite capable of handling intensive GUI applications where the ANTS profiler does not do so well.

dotTrace will tell you line by line where the culprit is. dotTrace is made by JetBrains who gave us ReSharper.

Comment: Is there a tutorial for dorTrace memory? I can't work out how to decipher what is keeping objects in memory.